# Flash of vote count when voting

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, voting, design, user-experience

There is a flash of the vote count before displaying a message. The message explains that a user can't vote on their own content.

When voting on your own content:

[image: An example of upvoting my own question]

It should just display the message instantly if a user does click on it and avoid the flash and the server round trip all together.

---

*Note: This question has been heavily edited, please view the history to see the original post if interested.*

Comment: If it ain't broken, don't fix it

Comment: To @Oded who edited my question to include the tag "status-by-design" - I didn't know it was by design, I'm going to revert the edit to my old tags. Thanks for your answer below.

Comment: Oh moderator only tags are new to me. Carry on :-)

Comment: @DauhFhauc - I am a dev on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner @probablyPekka , I guess you're right. I wish e-mail would evolve to something else though ;-)

Comment: @Dauh oh yeah, amen to that.

Comment: You'd have to have the server side checks anyway because you should never trust the client, so why duplicate the checks

Comment: @RichardTingle It would prevent the flash of numbers as I've stated, and would reduce the (although negligibly small) data transfer that occurs.

Comment: @DauhFhauc I see you're active on Stack overflow so I assume you're familiar with the concept of premature optimisation. While this would be worth changing if the data was significant but at negligible data transfer it would actually be negligent to change this as it could introduce (real) bugs with no actual gain

Comment: @RichardTingle Very familiar with the subject. I'm used to working with detail oriented people - it just caught my eye form a UX standpoint. I'm not sure how long StackOverflow has been around & it's obviously not a concern of theirs. I'm going to have to remove this question to get out of the red. I can't ask new questions on this site anymore due to the downvotes I've received for asking this question.

Comment: @DauhFhauc Be aware if you are question banned then deleting your questions is the very worst thing you can do

Comment: @RichardTingle Can you point me in the right direction then? My questions as you can see haven't been all that favorable. I was hoping that this one would do as well as my other style concern issue (CSS notifications) but it did the opposite for me. If I wait 6 months then delete my questions is that any better?

Comment: Agreed, the flash of numbers is annoying. Perhaps you should rephrase your question to focus on that, instead of the (negligible) data transfer. Also, there's absolutely no reason at all for the vote arrows to be clickable on your own posts. The server knows they are your own posts before it serves them, disabling the arrows is extremely simple.

Comment: @DauhFhauc Deleting your own questions makes things worse under all circumstances. Editing existing questions so they get upvotes (Yannis makes a very fair suggestion for editing this one) is the best thing you can do. Second to that (and a poor second) is answer questions

Comment: Re edit: this question is basically a request for developers to change things so it avoids the 0.3kb transfer. The downvotes are people saying that this doesn't need changing and the developers should spend their time on the [huge number of other ideas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)

Answer (score 13):

The server is what determines whether you are or not allowed to vote on a post.

The UI cannot and should not make that determination - a round trip is the right thing to do here.

Comment: I guess my reasoning was you can do the check on the client side first AND on the server side. We aren't in the 90's anymore with forms. There is such a thing as client-side verification as well. Obviously you don't trust it and double check on the server side...

Comment: @DauhFhauc - so, if we do it on the server side **anyways**, why block it on the client side?

Comment: This has happened to me maybe 30 times in four years. I generate more regular requests in a half hour on SO

Comment: @DauhFhauc Other than voting on your own question, which not many people do, how else would this be used anyways? I find it funny how you tag the question as a bug..

Comment: @probablyPekka Wow; you've tried to vote for yourself about half of the times I have myself!

Comment: @Oded, this is just me nit picking as it's a trivial amount of data... But if I was on a mobile device it would waste data. A simple example of a more real-world situation would be uploading an image. Instead of wasting the bandwidth to upload the image and *then* check the size, why not check the size on the client side first. Another reason to do this is to avoid that flash of numbers which is more of a user experience problem.

Comment: @DauhFhauc Based on your gif above, it's only transferring .3kb.. meanwhile the size of the gif alone is 1.8MB !

Comment: As long as we are being over-pedantic: Why are the vote arrows on your own posts clickable in the first place?

Comment: @Yannis +1 for the thought, but I think being clickable makes the user click it, and then they are presented with the message on why they can't click it ;-) . It's a great learning experience that I think is the right way to do it vs. having the users read a manual about how to use the site. Learn by... experience I suppose.

Comment: @DauhFhauc You can still show the message, if you want. All the server needs to do is (for example) add an `.own_post` class on the arrows. When the client catches a click on an `.own_post` arrow, it could go straight to the message, skipping the round trip validation and the annoying numbers flash.

Answer (score 1):

Any change to a code base has to weigh risks and costs against rewards. In this case it breaks down as follows

## Downsides

#### Costs

- Developer time
- Tester time

#### Risks

- Possibility to introduce bugs (as with all code changes)

## Upsides

- A reduction in a negligible amount of data transfer than no one will ever notice (without instrumentation) in a situation that affects users very rarely

All in all the negligible upsides vs moderate costs there is no reason to change this. If anything it would be negligent to change this.

Comment: Thanks for the true answer to my question & I agree with your statements. Unfortunately the reputation you gain from my up vote will be lost - I've received too many down votes from this question and have been banned from posting any new questions till I fix my negative reputation. Edit: I can try removing other posts first and save you the reputation loss.

Comment: @DauhFhauc The reputation Richard and Oded earned from their answers won't be affected by your (unfortunate) question ban. If you are about to delete your question, I'm afraid you can't do that since it has upvoted answers.

Comment: @Yannis Good to hear, thanks. :-)

Comment: @DauhFhauc - deleted posts are considered in the question ban. Deleting them means you will not be _able_ to improve them in order to get it lifted (it is automatic).

Comment: @Oded Is there any way out of the fox hole? I thought this question would do well on here (based from my other CSS related notification question). If my posts are old how can I recover? I can't really alter my old questions - the community didn't like their *topic*, not their *quality of content*. I can make a lot of false accounts and upvote myself, but that doesn't seem ethical... going to look for related questions. Have a good day Mr. Oded.

Comment: @DauhFhauc - I gave you a hand up there, but you are still rather close to the threshold. I can only suggest that you don't ask something controversial or trivial for your next questions...

Comment: aww @Oded, I'll revise my old questions and get it the hard earned way. Thanks though. I'm running out for lunch, I'll clean up my questions though I may make the answers irrelevant in the process as I fine tune them.

Comment: @DauhFhauc - No. That's worse - don't make answers irrelevant.

Comment: Back from lunch - I'll do general cleanup and make sure they don't become irrelevant. My edits to this question may have done that, but I included a disclaimer at the end of my post for others to view the revision history. Edit: It appears edits bump posts to the top and may gather unwanted down votes. The edit to this question just granted me another down vote even though it's no longer nitpicking. I'll just not edit anything and stay low for awhile & make my profile name more professional along with the user image.

Comment: @Dauh hmm, perhaps. It really shouldn't matter but there is something about your user image, somehow it's angering